# Insert now() using Cassandra's Java Object-mapping API

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

What is the equivalent of:

```
INSERT INTO table (myColumn) VALUES (now())
```

using the Cassandra object-mapping api?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@Computed` annotation doesnt look like it would work unfortunately.

You can also set the value of your object to a type1 uuid. The jre doesnt have standard function for it but you can use the [java driver util](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/UUIDs.html#timeBased--), [JUG](http://mediashelf.github.io/uuid-datepath-idmapper/generate_uuids.html), [cassandra-all](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/utils/UUIDGen.java#L70) or even write one yourself. This would be a little different because your setting the time as the time of creation as opposed to coordinator setting time of when it receives the request but with ORM's abstractions you tend to lose some control.

Alternatively there is nothing preventing you from issuing CQL statements while still using the object mapping api. Maybe even [adding a query to a method](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver/common/drivers/reference/accessorAnnotatedInterfaces.html) on your object to do it ie:

```
@Query("UPDATE table SET myColumn = now() WHERE ....")
public ResultSet setNow()
```

Comment: I was hoping there was something easy, like:
https://github.com/valchkou/cassandra-driver-mapping#id-uuid-and-timeuuid